# Erro fora do range da lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Opa estou com um problema, tenho 3 arquivos que preciso abrir e pegar informações deles, passar para uma lista dentro de lista (matriz?!) e comparar informações de 2 listas com outra lista para validar algo. Um dos arquivos (o de técnicos) detém matrículas de técnicos, outro (regiões) detém cidades onde ocorreram pesquisas IBGE e no ultimo é o arquivo da pesquisa IBGE, eu tenho que saber se todos os técnicos que estão no arquivo de pesquisa IBGE existem no arquivo de técnicos e se as cidades que estão no arquivo pesquisa existem no arquivo regiões que armazenam todas as cidade que houve a pesquisa. Eu consigo passar as informações para uma "matriz", e comparar a informação no entanto, eu estou fazendo a comparação entre as listas porém existe uma parte do meu código que dá esse erro:
IndexError: list index out of range
Eu não consegui ver algo errado até o momento nisso, já modifiquei diversas vezes, coloquei condições (essas condições que coloquei se relaciona com os arquivos, eu basicamente fiz igualei algumas coisas para que não ultrapassasse o range dos arquivos) para que não ultrapasse o range porém o erro persiste. 
O meu código é esse:

```
pesquisa = []
arq_pesq = open('Pesquisa.txt', 'r')
matrizex=arq_pesq.readlines()
for line in matrizex[:]: 
    #Separa a string por ;
    Type = line.split(";") 
    a = Type[0] 
    b = Type[1]
    c = Type[2]
    d = Type[3]
    e = Type[4]
    f = Type[5]
    g = Type[6]
    h = Type[7]
    i = Type[8]
    j = Type[9]
    k = Type[10]
    l = Type[11]
    m = Type[12]
    n = Type[13]
    o = Type[14]
    p = Type[15]
    q = Type[16]
    r = Type[17]
    s = Type[18]
    t = Type[19]
    v= Type[20]
for i in range(1):
    linha = []
    for j in range(1):
        linha.append(Type)
    pesquisa.append(linha)


tecnicos=[]
arquivo_tec=open("tecnicosIBGE.txt" , 'r')
linhas=arquivo_tec.readlines()
for line in linhas[:]: 
    #Separa a string por ;
    Type = line.split(";") 
    a = Type[0] 
    b = Type[1]
    c = Type[2]
    d = Type[3]
    for i in range(1):
    linha = []
        for j in range(1):
            linha.append(Type)
        tecnicos.append(linha)

erros=[]   
n=200
c=142
contador=1
print(tecnicos[n][0][0])
print(pesquisa[c][0][0])
while True:
    n=200
    c=c-1
    contador=1
while(c!=0 or n!=0):
    if(c==0):
        break
    #O erro indica essa próxima linha
    elif tecnicos[n][0][0] in pesquisa[c][0][0]:
        print("Achou")
        print(tecnicos[n][0][0])
        print(pesquisa[c][0][0])
        n=200
        break
    else:
        if n==0:
            erros=pesquisa[c].append
            #del(pesquisa[c])
            break
        n=n-1
        if n==0:
            break
        contador=contador+1
        print(tecnicos[n][0][0])
        print(pesquisa[c][0][0])
        print("Não achou ",contador)
```

[Arquivos necessários para o programa](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_6ZBDbT9c_T-axHw-h0WomMQDeVG-Gvo?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Isso te atende?

```
import csv

csv_tec = None
tec_matriculas = set()
with open('tecnicos.csv', mode = 'r') as f:
  csv_tec = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = ';', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
  tec_matriculas = set([ x.get('Matrícula') for x in csv_tec])

csv_pes = None
pesq_tec = set()
with open('pesquisas.csv', mode = 'r') as f:
  csv_pes = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = ';', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
  pesq_tec = set([ x.get("Técnico") for x in csv_pes ])

print(all(tecnico_pesquisa in tec_matriculas for tecnico_pesquisa in pesq_tec))
```

A ideia aqui é aproveitar o [módulo csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) do Python e ler como um OrderedDict (já com as chaves). Aqueles dois  set(...)  servem apenas p/ remover entradas duplicadas.
A função   all  vai retornar  True  se para todo elemento no  pesq_tec  (guardado na variável tecnico_pesquisa) existe um correspondente no conjunto das matrículas extraídas do arquivo de técnicos.